# I can't  use a database in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to use a Database in SQL Azure. I have installed SQL Server 2008. I can Login SQL Azure and can use master Database. But I can't use other Database and I can't see any things in my object explorer. It shows this error:

```
"USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database."
```

How can I use another database?

Comment: In SQL Azure, each database has its own connection. To switch to another database, you need to open a new connection. You cannot use "USE" as the error clearly says....

Comment: can I connect this SQLServer 2008 Ent. Edition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the Solution for this problem . I install `SQL Server 2008 R2`. then every thing is ok...

Comment: This is a known problem and the OP fixed it with a known solution. The solution that worked should not have been downvoted. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2292807

Comment: The problem is, it is not working with Azure SQL Databases.

Comment: Almost 2022, not working for sqlcmd from bash on Focal either,

Answer (score 7):

You cannot link to another database server from SQL Azure, whether that other database is SQL Server or SQL Azure.

Comment: This message is generally for databases under the same server. This was (and still is) a major issue for sqlcmd, This must be by intent, you are forced to specify the -d switch  on the command line and cannot jump between databases.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can first create only the database before running the whole script to create schemas & Tables.
2. Then manually change the database to the new DB that was created.
3. Run the rest of the script. Do not run `Use <databasename>`

Answer (score -2):

Posting incase anyone else runs into this i had to wrap the DB name in []

so

USE [DBNAMEHERE]

instead of

USE DBNAMEHERE